# Auto detect OS of device in appium

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, appium, appium-ios

I am using `appium_lib`to automate my tests in both iOS and Android

Currently, I am maintaining two suites, one for android seperately and another for iOS.

Is there a provision in this cucumber with appium_lib gem, to maintain the cases for both iOS and Android both in a single suite? And let appium automatically detect which device is connected, and execute the test cases tagged accordingly?

Like if Appium detects it to be iOS, run the test cases that are tagged under iOS `cucumber -t @ios`

I understand `env.rb` could be of help in this and in `hooks.rb` under `before do` I could provide a `if` and `else` condition with

```
    if $driver.device_is_android? == 'true'
    'cucumber -t @Android'
  else
    'cucumber -t @iOS'
  end
```

Something like this? Is it possible? I am unable to find information on the internet with respect to auto detect of device OS, and hence posted this as a question with my thoughts.

I understand I can read the versions of the OS with the command `adb shell getprop | grep build.version.release` , and hence wanted to know if its possible to read the OS with one common command, apart from `$driver.device_is_android?`

Now to run the cucumber cases, for iOS and Android, I need to pass individual capabilities in appium. Is there a way to do it programmatically in the `if` and `else` condition itself?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem, even I'm searching for answer.

Comment: Yes! I ll post the answer, as to what I did. I actually created two sets of desired capabilities and invoking appium only when the same is being called and not when the execution started. So, in this case, I am calling iOS capability only when the device is not android.

Comment: can you please post answer & accept as well, it can be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this dilema but I solved differently.

In our case we are using Cucumber on top of Appium so I just execute it with an argument that represents my platform, for example:

cucumber PLATFORM=iOS

Then in my env.rb I get the argument:

@platform = ENV['PLATFORM']

And then I just use it to get the capabilities I want:

```
if @platform == "DROID"
  Appium::Driver.new(droid_caps, true)
else
  Appium::Driver.new(ios_caps, true)
end
```

When you are running a test you always know which platform you are testing so it makes sense to send it as an argument.

Comment: True! Declaring cucumber variables is smart though. I am using this for testing on various browsers, by having a `ENV['BROWSER']